# How to cancel the subscription with stripe

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments

I am working on asp.net web application using c#. I am trying to work on stripe api for credit card transactions and subscriptions. I have followed the documentation present in stripe official site and also sample project XamarinStripe available on github. Now i am trying to cancel the subscription of a particular customer but i am unable to accomplish it using Xamarin dll. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on [Stripe's website](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions).

As for how to do it using XamarinStripe, the unit tests for the assembly [has an example](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinStripe/blob/master/PaymentTest/Program.cs):

```
static StripeSubscription TestDeleteSubscription (StripeCustomer customer, StripePayment payment)
{
    StripeSubscription sub = payment.Unsubscribe (customer.ID, true);
    return sub;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want cancel the subscription using the classes present in xamarin.dll file like stripesubscription, stripepayment etc which are written in c# but i am unable to implement the unsubscription.